# Need help understanding Big-O

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I'm in a Data Structures class now, and we're covering Big-O as a means of algorithm analysis. Unfortunately after many hours of study, I'm still somewhat confused. I understand what Big-O is, and several good code examples I found online make sense. However I have a homework question I don't understand. Any explanation of the following would be greatly appreciated.

> Determine how many times the output statement is executed in each of
>   the following fragments (give a number in terms of n). Then indicate
>   whether the algorithm is O(n) or O(n2):
>
> ```
>     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
>         for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
>             if (j % i == 0)
>                 System.out.println(i + ” ” + j);
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose n = 5. Then, the values of i would be 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4. This means that means that the inner loop will iterate 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 times, respectively. Because of this, the total number of times that the `if` comparison will execute is 1+2+3+4+5. A mathematical formula for the sum of integers from 1 to n is n*(n+1)/2. Expanded, this gives us n^2 / 2 + n / 2.
Therefore, the algorithm itself is **O(n^2)**.

For the number of times that something is printed, we need to look at the times that j%i=0. When j < i, the only time that this can be true is when j = 0, so this is the number of times that j = 0 and i is not 0. This means that it is only true once in each iteration of the outer loop, except the first iteration (when i = 0).
Therefore, System.out.println is called **n-1 times**.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to look at it is :

A single loop has a complexity of O(n)

A loop within a loop has a complexity of O(n^2) and so on.

So the above loop has a complexity of O(n^2)

Comment: This is the exact same information that I had posted earlier with the caveat that @Nabla pointed out.

Answer (score -1):

This function appears to execute in Quadratic Time - O(n^2).

Here's a trick for something like this.  For each nested for loop add one to the exponent for n.  If there was three loops this algorithm would run in cubic time O(n^3).  If there is only one loop (no halving involved) then it would be linear O(n).  If the array was halved each time (recursively or iteratively) it would be considered logarithmic time O(log n) -> base 2.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Note that these rules, while applicable in many common cases, are not true generally and one should know about their validity range.

Comment: @Nabla - good point, but this is a good starting point for someone that is trying to get their head wrapped around asymptotic analysis for the first time.

Comment: This function is not quadratic time. `j < i` in the second inner loop ensures this. If it were `j < n`, then yes, it would be, but as a whole the `j` loop only approaches O(n) w.r.t `i` when `i` is at its closest to `n`.

Comment: @kvanberendonck There are `i` iterations of the inner loop per `i`. `i` goes from `0` to `n`, so there will be `sum_(i=0...n) i` iterations of the inner loop in total, which is about `n*(n+1)/2`, ergo quadratic. That said, the question was regarding the number of calls of the output, which is something different. But even then you get O(n).

Comment: The function behaves similar to a basic selection sort - just going the opposite way.  For this to behave in O(log n) - it would need to be cut in half each time - like how a binary search behaves.  This is not the case here.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your feedback. This helps greatly. Such a great community.